# Can't switch default language on Opera

Tags: windows, language, opera

I installed Opera in `English (United Kingdom)`, but I noticed `English (Canada)` was available in `opera://settings` so I decided to switch to so. The changes required a browser restart, so I clicked the provided hyperlink to restart.

[image: switching to Canadian English]

After the restart, Opera's language is *still* set to `English (United Kingdom)`.

How can I force Opera to change the language? Is there a registry key I can modify perhaps?

**Opera version:** Opera beta 36.0.2130.29

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro

Comment: It should be noted you are using the beta version of Opera. Perhaps this is a bug in that particular build? Have you checked the release notes?

Comment: @Burgi I'm with build 37.0.2178.10 now, and the bug is still present.  The [release notes](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/changelog-37/) mention spellcheck bugs, but my spellcheck is fully operational.

Comment: According to the [language list](https://www.opera.com/download/languagefiles/) there isn't a Canadian English version available.

Comment: @Burgi Added an image.

Comment: I saw that when I installed a copy just now. See my answer for the bad news :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no language pack for English (Canadian). Opera lists all the possible languages even if it doesn't have a language pack for that particular language available.

The [Opera help files](http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/language.html) mention that if a you choose a language that Opera doesn't have a pack for it will default to the last good language pack (in this instance, English (UK)).

> Note that Opera is not necessarily available in all languages on the list, nor will most websites serve content based on your language setting. Should no Opera translation exist in your preferred language, the software will remain in US English, while some websites may serve you content in the selected language.

This is further backed up by the lack of Canadian language pack in the [localization folder](http://www.opera.com/docs/operafiles/). In my case I found the language packs here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera beta\37.0.2178.19\localization
```

[image: Opera localization folder]

Comment: Aw... I'm gonna miss my _favourite_ language.  Good answer though ;)

Comment: I'm British, I just think `zed` gets underused ;)